# How to mock and test conditional bootstrapping via ngDoBootstrap in AppModule

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

Looking for suggestions on how to test conditional bootstrapping via AppModule and ngDoBootstrap in Angular. I have tried mocking the ApplicationRef but have ran into numerous errors including:

> The selector "component-a" did not match any elements

This seems to indicate the DOM is not loaded during test execution (makes sense). I have tried manually creating the component and mocking the ApplicationRef and Document objects with no success.

**app.module.ts**

```
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

  // Conditionally bootstrap components
  ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef): void {
    if (this.document.querySelector('component-a')) {
      appRef.bootstrap(AComponent);
    }

    if (this.document.querySelector('component-b')) {
      appRef.bootstrap(BComponent);
    }

    if (this.document.querySelector('component-c')) {
      appRef.bootstrap(CComponent);
    }
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Information</title>
  <base href="/">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="layout">
    <main class="layout__content">
      <section class="layout__section padding-l">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <component-a></component-a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <component-b></component-b>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <component-c></component-c>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How could there be a dom before angular has bootstrapped? Are you looking for something in `index.html`?

Comment: Correct, that seems to be the problem I'm trying to solve. How do I bootstrap the components and get past the error by testing the conditional logic via mocking instead of relying on the existence of the element on index.html.

Comment: Ok, could you show us your `index.html` then?

Comment: I added `index.html`. The application renders without any issue since all of the elements exist. The problem is when I try to unit test the code.